# Strange behavior with host instance account and Dynamics Ax adapter

Tags: biztalk, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, biztalk-2010

We have encountered a behavior that I'm having trouble to understand.

We have a receive port (WCF) with a receive handler ReceiveHost running under account1 and a send port (Dynamics Ax adapter) with a sendhandler SendHost running under account2.
On the adapter properties we have specified account2 as both gateway user and proxy user.

When we send a message through BizTalk to Dynamics Ax we get an error in Dynamics saying that account1 is is not a recognized user of Microsoft Dynamics AX.

How can Axapta know of account1 at all?

Comment: That's a strange one... You have checked that your Send Handler is running against SendHost and that SendHost is configured to run as 'account2'? Alternatively, you are not running a Dynamic ('dynamic', not 'Dynamics') Send Port when talking to AX and it is defaulting to a Handler configured as 'account1'?

Comment: Yes, my Send Handler is running against SendHost and there is no dynamic port. I changed the receive handler to a host that is running under account 2 and everything works as expected.

Comment: RobinHu, can you add an update to your question detailing your fix so your question can be closed?

Comment: Haven't found any explanation to this yet

Answer (score 0):

This message is received when the user doesn't exists on AX. You can manually create users or easilly import them to AX from active directory. It's well docummented on TechNet:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa497043.aspx

Comment: Maybe I should'nt had tagged the post with Dynamics Ax since it is more  a BizTalk related question. The question is not about how to fix the problem but rather why BizTalk calls Dynamics with account1 and not account2.

Comment: As AX is who complaints about the user, I've tagged that way so that other AX buddies can find that question, and may be give us a solution.